# Python glob where file names look like regexes

Tags: python, glob

I have an interesting issue that I can't resolve, maybe someone has seen it before.

The simplified example is as follows: we have a directory called "a[2-1]" that we list the files in using `glob.glob(f"{path}/*")`. Glob reads the argument as a regex and crashes because `2-1` is not a valid interval. It looks like the [] are still handled as special characters, regardless of how many backslashes I put in front of them.

Any ideas?

```
>>> glob.glob(r"a[2-1*")
['a[2-1]']
>>> glob.glob(r"a[2-1]*")
re.error: bad character range 2-1 at position 6
>>> glob.glob(r"a[2-1\]*")
re.error: bad character range 2-1 at position 6
>>> glob.glob(r"a[2-1\\]*")
re.error: bad character range 2-1 at position 6
>>> glob.glob(r"a[2-1\\\]*")
re.error: bad character range 2-1 at position 6
```

Comment: Nah, it fails in Python3.8: `In [39]: glob.glob(r"a\[2\-1\]*")` `error: bad character range \\-1 at position 9`. `re.compile` works, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [glob-doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) says that the match is done with [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html). It tells you:

> For a literal match, wrap the meta-characters in brackets. For example, `'[?]'` matches the character `'?'`.

So you should use:

```
glob.glob('a[[]2-1[]]*')
```